# Rails 5.2 returning 406 with Axios Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vue.js, cross-domain, axios

I have a rails API in Rails 5.2 and a frontend in Vuejs, using Axios to request API.
When I request with postman on route

> [GET] http://localhost:3000/foo

I get the expected JSON response.

But when I request with Axios :

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  getAll () {
    return axios.get('http://localhost:3000/foo', {
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    })
  }
}
```

I got this response from the server :

> CleanwalksController#index is missing a template for this request format and variant. request.formats: ["text/html"] request.variant: []

I have the following config/cors.rb :

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*',
      headers: :any,
      methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head]
  end
end
```

I got the same issue when I try to access to **http://localhost:3000/foo** directly.

Here is my controller :

```
class FooController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @foo = foo.all
  end

end
```

Comment: Have you tried calling  http://localhost:3000/foo.json to force the request to use the JSON variant (rather than relying on the header)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem comes from your view, do you have a file named index.html.erb. Otherwise, you can define multiple response format as following :

```
class FooController < ApplicationController

def index
  @foo = foo.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :index }
    format.json { render json: @foo, status: 200 }
  end
end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the exact same issue. Everything worked perfectly in my specs and in postman, but for some reason I was getting a 406 with vue/axios.

After much hair pulling I discovered a typo in my routes file:

```
namespace :v1, default: { format: :json } do
```

It should have been defaults (plural)

```
namespace :v1, defaults: { format: :json } do
```